# Php form array not passing values to other pages

Tags: php, arrays, forms, post

I am working on a project where I want users to choose their space for parking and book it. I have a MySQL database which holds information about parking slots. I am fetching those values and display it using table and form. I have put checkboxes to make choice. and once they make choice they should be directed to payment page.

I am having problem with checkbox. I can see that in value fields it has values from database but when I hit submit button it doesn't pass any values to next page.

below is my code

```
<body>
    <form  method="POST" action="book.php">
    <?php
    //we create a table
    echo "<table>";
    // create table th 
    echo "<tr > <th> Parking Slot No </th> <th> Status </th>";
    $sql=" select ParkingSlotNo,Status from fleming_dwing  ";
    $st=$conn->prepare($sql);
    $st->execute();
    $total=$st->rowCount();//get the number of rows returned
    if($total < 1 ){//if no row was returned
        echo "<tr> <td style> No Data: DataBase Empty </td> ";//print out error message
        echo "<td> No Data: DataBase Empty </td> ";//print out error message
        $ing =  "<img src='img/occupied.png'/>" ;


    }
        else{
    while($res = $st->fetchObject()){//loop through the returned rows
        echo "<tr>";
        if($res->ParkingSlotNo and $res->Status=='OCCUPIED')
        {echo "<td> $res->ParkingSlotNo </td> ";
        echo "<td>   <img src='img/occupied.png'/> </td>";
            echo"<td><a href=''> </a> </td>";
            } 
            else
             {
        echo "<td> $res->ParkingSlotNo </td> ";

        echo "<td> <img src='img/vacant.png'> </td>";
        echo"<td><input type='checkbox' value='$res->ParkingSlotNo'></td>";
        }

    echo"</tr>";

    }
    }


    ?>
    </table>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">

    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

and this is the code for booking page

```
<?php
require_once("dbconfigpdo.php");
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to set an attribute `name` to your input field, or it will not be processed. 
Something like:

```
<input name='parkingslot' type='checkbox' value='$res->ParkingSlotNo'>
```

Answer (score 2):

The checkboxes do not have `name` attributes. A form control can't be successful (included in the `name=value` pairs of data that are submitted) without one.

Answer (score 1):

Any `input` **must have** a `name` attribute.

By `name` you can use a value. So, you need to add `name="your name"` to your checkboxes.